# correlated update in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

there are two tables jobs and employees. i want to displace emloyees.first_name with jobs.job_title.
wnen i do like this:

`update employees
set first_name= (select distinct job_title from jobs,employees where 
employees.job_id=jobs.job_id)`
 QL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row occure.

tryed to do it with cursor, but there was the same error.
Could you please tell me how to update muliple rows on the basis of another table?

Comment: It looks strange to set the employee's first name to a job title. Is that really what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a correlated subquery, the outer table almost *never* goes in the correlated subquery.  I imagine you really want:

```
update employees
    set first_name = (select job_title
                      from jobs
                      where employees.job_id = jobs.job_id
                     );
```

Setting a first name to a job title seems weird, but that seems to be the intention of your query.

I am guessing that `job_id` is unique for the table `jobs`, so this should fix your problem.  If not, adding a `and rownum = 1` would ensure that at most one row is returned.

Comment: And generally you'd want to have a `where exists` so that you only update a row in `employees` if there is a corresponding row in `jobs`.